# Can't import os.listdir

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path

I have a quick question.
I try to import 'os.listdir' with

```
import os.listdir
```

However, it shows me an error like below.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'os.listdir'; 'os' is not a package

  File "/Users/chanwooahn/Google Drive/Projects/The Economist/main.py", line 1, in

 <module>import os.listdir

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

I thought 'os' is a built-in interface of python.
I have updated 'conda' and 'python', but still, it gave me the same error.
Is there any possible reason for this?

Comment: `from os import listdir`?

Comment: @Rakesh ...That works. What's the difference???

Answer (score 3):

yea, you should use from:

```
from os import listdir
```

listdir is not a package ;)

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `import` needs to be a package name. `os` does not contain a package named `listdir` so you can't import that.

What you *can* do is

```
import os
os.listdir('.')
```

or just import `listdir` specifically:

```
from os import listdir
listdir('.')
```

or with a twist:

```
from os import listdir as ld
ld('.')
```

There is some variability within the Python standard library where some packages do contain subpackages which you can or even have to `import` specifically; but `listdir` is just a function within the `os` package, and not a package by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import os

all_files = os.listdir("C:\\Sample")
print(all_files)
```